# ValueError: If passed as a pd.DataFrame, X must be a nested pd.DataFrame, with pd.Series or np.arrays inside cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Here I have used ROCKET transform - ROCKET [1] transforms time series using random convolutional kernels (random length, weights, bias, dilation, and padding). ROCKET computes two features from the resulting feature maps: the max, and the proportion of positive values (or ppv). The transformed features are used to train a linear classifier.

Then used ridgeclassifier together with ROCKET in a pipeline. the pipeline is acting like a self contained classifier, with a single call to fit, and without having to separately transform the data, etc.)

```
from sktime.transformations.panel.rocket import Rocket
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifierCV
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
rocket = Rocket()
rocket_pipeline = make_pipeline(
      Rocket(), RidgeClassifierCV(alphas=np.logspace(-3, 3, 10), normalize=True)
)
rocket_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm getting this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-08cfcb34f61e> in <module>()
      4     Rocket(), RidgeClassifierCV(alphas=np.logspace(-3, 3, 10), normalize=True)
      5 )
----> 6 rocket_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
      7 X_train_transform = rocket.transform(X_train)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    388         """
    389         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 390         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    391         with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    392             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    353                 message_clsname="Pipeline",
    354                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 355                 **fit_params_steps[name],
    356             )
    357             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892         if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894         else:
    895             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sktime/transformations/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, Z)
    559         # Non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    560         # method is possible for a given algorithm.
--> 561         return self.fit(X, y).transform(X, y)
    562 
    563     # def inverse_transform(self, Z, X=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sktime/transformations/panel/rocket/_rocket.py in fit(self, X, y)
     61         self
     62         """
---> 63         X = check_X(X, coerce_to_numpy=True)
     64         _, self.n_columns, n_timepoints = X.shape
     65         self.kernels = _generate_kernels(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sktime/utils/validation/panel.py in check_X(X, enforce_univariate, enforce_min_instances, enforce_min_columns, coerce_to_numpy, coerce_to_pandas)
    106         if not is_nested_dataframe(X):
    107             raise ValueError(
--> 108                 "If passed as a pd.DataFrame, X must be a nested "
    109                 "pd.DataFrame, with pd.Series or np.arrays inside cells."
    110             )

ValueError: If passed as a pd.DataFrame, X must be a nested pd.DataFrame, with pd.Series or np.arrays inside cells.
```

PS. My database (X here) is an array of [2047*200] consisting of numerical values. I'm trying to classify it in 5 classes each class will have 40 columns each. I have made 'y' accordingly (y is an array of 200 elements).
I have added the exact error as mentioned in the comment below. Hope this will help in identifying where exactly I went wrong.

Comment: Please edit your post to copy the error message exactly - something is missing (the exact like where the error occurs).

Comment: @desertnaut will an image do? if so, here's the link to it - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nk4U4rglO4mQgw3NqcdpP9HHO0bvUyby/view?usp=sharing

Comment: An image *never* does; please copy the exact text of the error and paste it in your post above *as is* (the arrow is important).

Comment: @desertnaut I have added the complete error with arrows as you mentioned. Would be helpful if you can help me

Comment: What is `Rocket()`, and where does it come from? Please include explicitly your *relevant* imports.

Comment: @desertnaut I have added the relevant imports and what they mean